# How do I get past the 404 with Activiti Explorer

Tags: activiti

I'd ask the Activiti forum, but these three poor unfortunates all asked to no avail:

- http://forums.activiti.org/en/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=3940
- http://forums.activiti.org/en/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=3606
- http://forums.activiti.org/en/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=2667

So, I ask you, StackOverflow... can you help? The antfile looks to be executing without any problems:

```
C:\activiti-5.9\setup>ant demo.start
Buildfile: C:\activiti-5.9\setup\build.xml

demo.install:

internal.cfg.create:
     [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\activiti-5.9\setup\build\activiti-cfg
      [zip] Building zip: C:\activiti-5.9\setup\build\activiti-cfg.jar
     [echo] copying configuration to ../workspace/activiti-engine-examples/src/main/config
    [unzip] Expanding: C:\activiti-5.9\setup\build\activiti-cfg.jar into C:\activiti-5.9\workspace\activiti-engine-examples\src\ma
in\config

internal.classpath.libs:

internal.taskdef.launch:

h2.start:
     [echo] starting H2 database...
   [launch] launching cmd 'C:\activiti-5.9\apps\h2\h2.start.bat ' in dir 'C:\activiti-5.9\apps\h2'
   [launch] waiting for launch completion msg 'TCP server running on'...
   [launch]   TCP server running on tcp://192.168.168.62:9092 (others can connect)
     [echo] H2 database started

tomcat.start:
   [launch] launching cmd 'C:\activiti-5.9\apps\apache-tomcat-6.0.32\bin\startup.bat ' in dir 'C:\activiti-5.9\apps\apache-tomcat-
6.0.32\bin'
   [launch] waiting for launch completion msg 'Using CLASSPATH:'...
   [launch]   Using CATALINA_BASE:   "c:\tomcat"
   [launch]   Using CATALINA_HOME:   "c:\tomcat"
   [launch]   Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "c:\tomcat\temp"
   [launch]   Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\jre"
   [launch]   Using CLASSPATH:       "c:\tomcat\bin\bootstrap.jar;c:\tomcat\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"

explorer.browser.open:

demo.start:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 5 seconds
```

Tomcat reports:

```
May 21, 2012 10:08:21 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
May 21, 2012 10:08:21 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-443"]
May 21, 2012 10:08:21 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
May 21, 2012 10:08:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 619 ms
May 21, 2012 10:08:21 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
May 21, 2012 10:08:21 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.20
May 21, 2012 10:08:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory docs
May 21, 2012 10:08:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory examples
May 21, 2012 10:08:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory host-manager
May 21, 2012 10:08:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory manager
May 21, 2012 10:08:22 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
May 21, 2012 10:08:22 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-443"]
May 21, 2012 10:08:22 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
May 21, 2012 10:08:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 562 ms
```

Nothing added to the console when I request `http://localhost:8080/activiti-explorer`, but I do get:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1

Content-Length: 0

Date: Mon, 21 May 2012 15:09:09 GMT
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my resolution:

The CATALINA_* variables were pointing to my version of tomcat and not the one that comes with Activiti.

Setting

```
set CATALINA_BASE="C:\activiti-5.9\apps\apache-tomcat-6.0.32"
set CATALINA_HOME=%CATALINA_BASE%
set CATALINA_TEMP="C:\activiti-5.9\apps\apache-tomcat-6.0.32\temp"
```

Works fine from there.

Not sure if the same is applicable on a *nix system, but it's worth a look.